# Поиск и замена элементов в массиве

Tags: php

есть исходный массив $people:

```
 Array
 (
   [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Вася
        [1] => qwerty
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Федя
        [1] => asdf
    )
 )
```

и есть массив с заменами $replace:

```
Array
(
[qwerty] => Сидоренко
[asdf] => Пупкин
[аропао] => Константинопольский
[уншгнг] => Иванов
)
```

как сделать замену значений "qwerty" на "Сидоренко", "asdf" на "Пупкин" и так далее? Я понимаю что надо делать через foreach, но не получается. Делаю вот так:

```
foreach($people as &$value){
  if(isset($replace[$value])){
  $value = $replace[$value];
}
```

}

получаю ошибку: "Illegal offset type in isset or empty".

Answer (score 1):

`$value` - это **массив**, `$value[1]` - второй ключ массива:

```
foreach($people as &$value){
  if(isset($replace[$value[1]])){
      $value[1] = $replace[$value[1]];
  }
}
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, всё работает

Comment: Если ответ решает вашу проблему вы можете __принять__ его.